# SQL how to write a query that return missing date ranges?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am trying to figure out how to write a query that looks at certain records and finds missing date ranges between **today** and **9999-12-31**. 
My data looks like below:

```
ID      |start_dt                   |end_dt                     |prc_or_disc_1
10412   |2018-07-17 00:00:00.000    |2018-07-20 00:00:00.000    |1050.000000
10413   |2018-07-23 00:00:00.000    |2018-07-26 00:00:00.000    |1040.000000
```

So for this data I would want my query to return:

```
2018-07-10 | 2018-07-16
2018-07-21 | 2018-07-22
2018-07-27 | 9999-12-31
```

I'm not really sure where to start. Is this possible?

Comment: Gaps and Islands. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167068/solving-gaps-and-islands-with-row-number-and-dense-rank

Comment: Bleh, SQL Server 2008

Comment: Why are all the answers being deleted? Thanks for those who posted answers. I found that two of the solutions work.

Comment: @Ryan One answer is using a feature not available on SQL Server 2008, which the question is tagged with.

Comment: they're using `LEAD()` which was introduced in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Oh. I apologize for tagging it sql server 2008. I am on sql server 2014.

Comment: Well, now you have answers to both versions :)

Comment: Thank you for the help everyone. I spent way too much time trying to figure this out.

Comment: @Ryan - Please accept the answer you consider to be most correct and/or helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, end_dt, ISNULL(LEAD(start_dt) over (order by ID), '99991231')) > 1 then end_dt +1 END as F1,
    CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, end_dt, ISNULL(LEAD(start_dt) over (order by ID), '99991231')) > 1 then ISNULL(LEAD(start_dt) over (order by ID) - 1, '99991231') END as F2
from t
```

Working SQLFiddle example is -> [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1509b/7)

**FOR 2008 VERSION**

```
SELECT 
    X.end_dt + 1 as F1,
    ISNULL(Y.start_dt-1, '99991231') as F2
FROM t X
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT 
      *
    , (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM t WHERE ID < A.ID) as ID2
FROM t A) Y ON X.ID = Y.ID2
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, X.end_dt, ISNULL(Y.start_dt, '99991231')) > 1
```

Working SQLFiddle example is -> [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1509b/14)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using the lag() function in MS SQL (but that is available starting with 2012?).

```
 with myData as
    (
      select *, 
      lag(end_dt,1) over (order by start_dt) as lagEnd
      from myTable),
    myMax as
    (
      select Max(end_dt) as maxDate from myTable
    )
    select dateadd(d,1,lagEnd) as StartDate, dateadd(d, -1, start_dt) as EndDate
    from myData
    where lagEnd is not null and dateadd(d,1,lagEnd) < start_dt
    union all
    select dateAdd(d,1,maxDate) as StartDate, cast('99991231' as Datetime) as EndDate 
    from myMax
    where maxDate < '99991231';
```

If lag() is not available in MS SQL 2008, then you can mimic it with row_number() and joining.

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/65238/1

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    end_dt+1                            AS start_dt,
    LEAD(start_dt-1, 1, '9999-12-31')
      OVER (ORDER BY start_dt)
                                        AS end_dt
  FROM
    yourTable
)
  gaps
WHERE
  gaps.end_dt >= gaps.start_dt
```

I would, however, ***strongly*** urge you to use end dates that are "exclusive".  That is, the range is everything up to but excluding the `end_dt`.

That way, a range of one day becomes `'2018-07-09', '2018-07-10'`.

It's really clear that my range is one day long, if you subtract one from the other you get a day.

Also, if you ever change to needing hour granularity or minute granularity ***you don't need to change your data***.  It just works.  Always.  Reliably.  Intuitively.

If you search the web you'll find plenty of documentation on why inclusive-start and exclusive-end is a ***very*** good idea from a software perspective.  *(Then, in the query above, you can remove the wonky `+1` and `-1`.)*

Comment: For this I get the following error:
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

Comment: Oh it is because one of my dates was 9999-12-31

Comment: It looks like this works, but the one thing it does not do is find a date from today thru 9999-12-31. for example if my first record was gone from my sample data it would not find that date range.

Comment: That's because you didn't ask for that. Update your question with fully complete specific requirements.

Comment: Maybe it wasn't clear but I said "finds missing date ranges between today and 9999-12-31" sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @Ryan `UNION ALL SELECT getDate(), MIN(start_dt) FROM yourTable HAVING MIN(start_dt) > getDate()`

Answer (score 1):

This should work in 2008, it assumes that ranges in your table do not overlap.  It will also eliminate rows where the end_date of the current row is a day before the start date of the next row.

```
  with dtRanges as (
       select start_dt, end_dt, row_number() over (order by start_dt) as rownum 
       from table1
  )

  select t2.end_dt + 1, coalesce(start_dt_next -1,'99991231')
  FROM 
    (  select dr1.start_dt, dr1.end_dt,dr2.start_dt as start_dt_next
       from dtRanges dr1
       left join dtRanges dr2 on dr2.rownum = dr1.rownum + 1
    ) t2
  where 
  t2.end_dt + 1 <>  coalesce(start_dt_next,'99991231')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at this:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3a224/1
You just have to edit the begin range to today and the end range to 9999-12-31.

Comment: The link provided has no sql to run, only the schema. Also, you can also directly post the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

This solves your case, but provide some sample data if there will ever be overlaps, fringe cases, etc.

Take one day after your end date and 1 day before the next line's start date.

```
DECLARE @ TABLE (ID int, start_dt DATETIME, end_dt DATETIME, prc VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @ (id, start_dt, end_dt, prc)
VALUES 
(10410,   '2018-07-09 00:00:00.00','2018-07-12 00:00:00.000','1025.000000'),
(10412,   '2018-07-17 00:00:00.00','2018-07-20 00:00:00.000','1050.000000'),
(10413,   '2018-07-23 00:00:00.00','2018-07-26 00:00:00.000','1040.000000')


SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, end_dt)
, DATEADD(DAY, -1, LEAD(start_dt, 1, '9999-12-31') OVER(ORDER BY id) )
FROM @
```

Comment: Also returns records where there are no gaps (and so with a negative duration).  Needs to have those cases filtered out.