# Find missing date ranges between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, date-range, between

I have table which having data of some date ranges. when user select start date and end date then the result set will be like all date ranges between that 2 dates also all missing date ranges between that 2 dates.

**For Example:**
**DateRangesTable**

```
ID| fromdate  | todate    |
----------------------------
1 | 5-May-21  | 10-May-21 |
2 | 17-May-21 | 25-May-21 |
```

this is my main table ,I mention below all result set which I wanted with above table

if user select : **5-May-2021** to **25-May-2021**
Expected Result :

```
ID| fromdate  | todate    |
----------------------------
1 | 5-May-21  | 10-May-21 |
0 | 11-May-21 | 16-May-21 |
2 | 17-May-21 | 25-May-21 |
```

if user select : **6-May-2021** to **23-May-2021**
Expected Result :

```
ID| fromdate  | todate    |
-----------------------------
1 | 6-May-21  | 10-May-21 |
0 | 11-May-21 | 16-May-21 |
2 | 17-May-21 | 23-May-21 |
```

if user select : **1-May-2021** to **28-May-2021**
Expected Result :

```
ID| fromdate  | todate    |
----------------------------
1 | 1-May-21  | 4-May-21  |
1 | 5-May-21  | 10-May-21 |
0 | 11-May-21 | 16-May-21 |
2 | 17-May-21 | 25-May-21 |
2 | 26-May-21 | 28-May-21 |
```

Here some question which is not to similar but try to find:

[SQL Find missing date ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677472/sql-find-missing-date-ranges)

[SQL how to write a query that return missing date ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51254396/sql-how-to-write-a-query-that-return-missing-date-ranges)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have permission to share code .but I did this kind logic : ``` declare @startdate datetime
 declare @enddate datetime
 set @startdate = '2021-04-24 00:00:00.000'
 set @enddate = '2021-06-30 00:00:00.000'
 insert into @tempPeriod 
 select ID , FromDate , ToDate , 
 CID = lead(ID,1,null) over (Order By fromdate)
  from tablename
 where 
 (FromDate >= @startdate and FromDate <= @enddate) or
 (ToDate >= @startdate and ToDate <= @enddate)
```

Comment: [edit] any clarifications directly into the question. We don't want to see live code, we expect you to create a [mre] using test data and test code.

Comment: I don't understand the last expect result set; why does the first row have an `ID` of `1`, when those dates don't exist in the table, and why does the last have an `ID` of `2` for the same reason?

Comment: @DaleK it's my first question on this site and im trying this by my self. I understand what you are saying I will work on my mistake thanks for you guidance.

Comment: @Larnu, Sorry you are right by mistake I add ID Wrong ID's on last result set I wanted 0 ID of that records which is create Virtually. thanks

Comment: Yes, as I note my my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67720200/2029983) I *assumed* that to be the case, @shubhamkule .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A note, I am *assuming* here that the expected results for your final expected results is **wrong** here as it doesn't match the other 2. The last and first rows in the expected results for the last set both have a value for `ID` that isn't `0`, but no explanation of *why* they do is given. I therefore *assume* the value should be `0` like the row in the "middle".

To do this, I use a Tally to get all the dates between the date range you need; the Tally is limited to 1,000 rows, a little shy of 3 years, but you can cross join to `N` more if you need more rows. I then use that tally to create an inline calendar table. Next I `LEFT JOIN` that calendar to your data, and use a gaps and island method to put the values into groups. Finally I then aggregate on those groups, getting the `MIN` and `MAX` date in each one:

```sql
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (ID int,
                            FromDate date,
                            ToDate date);
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
VALUES(1,'20210505','20210510'),
      (2,'20210517','20210525');
GO

DECLARE @StartDate date = '20210501',
        @EndDate date = '20210528';

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT 0 AS I
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate))
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3), --1000 days
Dates AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, T.I, @StartDate) AS [Date],
           T.I
    FROM Tally T),
Grps AS(
    SELECT D.[Date],
           YT.ID,
           D.I - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY D.[Date]) AS Grp
    FROM Dates D
         LEFT JOIN dbo.YourTable YT ON D.[Date] >= YT.FromDate AND D.[Date] <= YT.ToDate)
SELECT ISNULL(MAX(G.ID),0) AS ID,
       MIN(G.[Date]) AS FromDate,
       MAX(G.[Date]) AS ToDate
FROM Grps G
GROUP BY G.Grp
ORDER BY FromDate ASC;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4ac2435dde31b940f0d79753a9f22ca7)

Comment: thanks for your quick response. it's work for me thank yo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all` for this:

```
-- first get the existing rows
select id,
       (case when fromdate < @fromdate then @fromdate else fromdate end) as fromdate,
       (case when todate > @todate then @todate else todate end) as to_date
from t
where fromdate < @todate and
      todate > @fromdate
union all
-- then the in-between rows
select 0, dateadd(day, 1, todate) as fromdate, next_fromdate as todate
from (select t.*,
             dateadd(day, -1, lead(fromdate) over (order by fromdate)) as next_fromdate
      from t
     ) t
where fromdate >= @fromdate and todate <= @todate and
      next_todate is not null
union all
-- then the earliest record, if any
select 0, @fromdate, min(fromdate)
from t
where todate > @fromdate
having @fromdate < min(fromdate) 
union all
-- then the final record, if any
select 0, max(todate), @todate
from t
where fromdate < @todate
having @todate > max(todate);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=63eb61415a852a56cb52fa9e95e01159) is a db<>fiddle.